# miss asm/types.h in linux compile

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
lenge@lenge-pc:/lenge/linux/kernel_online$ git branch 
  master  
* tag_v4.15 
CONFIG is defconfig.
```

when I compile `kernel(v4.15)`, error occurred, as follows:

In file included from

```
/lenge/linux/kernel_online/include/linux/types.h:6,
      from /lenge/linux/kernel_online/include/linux/page-flags.h:9,
      from /lenge/linux/kernel_online/kernel/bounds.c:10: 
/lenge/linux/kernel_online/include/uapi/linux/types.h:5:10: fatal
      error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory  #include <asm/types.h>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
```

That is my compile method:
`make ARCH=arm64 -C /lenge/linux/kernel_online O=/lenge/linux/kernel_out_aarch64 CROSS_COMPILE=/lenge/gnu/aarch64/bin/aarch64-lenge-linux-gnu- -j4`

I create symbolic link as fallows:

`ln -s /lenge/linux/kernel_out_aarch64/source/arch/arm64/include/generated/uapi/asm arch/arm64/include/generated/uapi/asm`

It's OK.

Comment: `make ARCH=arch ...`, where `arch` is what you are compiling for.

Comment: `make ARCH=arm64 -C /lenge/linux/kernel_online O=/lenge/linux/kernel_out_aarch64 CROSS_COMPILE=/lenge/gnu/aarch64/bin/aarch64-lenge-linux-gnu- -j4`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue cross-compiling to arm64.

I noticed I had some generated files in my source tree even though I use an output directory for my build (O=). I'm not sure if I accidentally omitted O= one time or what happened, but this was messing things up.

To resolve this, I ran make clean (or make mrproper if you're paranoid) in the source directory to remove all generated files. Rerunning my normal make command with O= succeeded, and did not result in generated files in my source dir (as expected).